# Ubuntu games fullscreen issues

Tags: multiple-monitors, games, minecraft, fullscreen

I have a dual monitor setup, where one of the monitors is vertical.

Distro is Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS, Gpu is 3060.

Up until today, I've had no problems with going fullscreen, but I repaired my monitor.
The problem is, that whenever i try to put, for example minecraft fullscreen, both monitors go dark for a few seconds, and pretty much one of two things happen,

1. The game immadiately minimizes
2. The resolution of the secondary monitor gets messed up(image)

[Also appeared on secondary *vertical* monitor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HCZks.jpg)
wallpaper supposed to be spanned

Any ideas about what could be the problem?
It seems like the monitor settings get reset to defaults during the fullscreen.

I've restarted the pc, reinstalled minecraft, reinstalled drivers.
The same happens on other games too.

Should I maybe reinstall the whole os?

Thanks in advance!

(edit) the problem seems to resolve itself when the second monitor is removed, but i don't know what could be the problem

Comment: You repaired the monitor? Why and what did you do? Maybe that is the issue.

Comment: @David It started making a sound as if a capacitor was about to blow up, but i actually didn't find anything wrong with it and i just put it back together and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is stupid....

Turns out, if you have the fractional scaling on in the display settings, it can mess things up.

I turned it off, and everything works fine, thanks for everyone who shared ideas!